# How to use AngularJS to show the html tag in the text

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to show some data in the html, the data like this:
    `<p>abcd efg hijk....(<a           href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/stock\/NBR\">NYSE:NBR<\/a>),`,as you see,there
 are some html tags, but when I use the angularJS to show these data, the Browser cannot recognize these data as html tag.

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: how you are applying. please share more code.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngBindHtml

```
<ANY
  ng-bind-html="expression">
...
</ANY>
```

Say you have value on $scope.htmtText = .... then

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmtText"></div>
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bind-html="myHTML"`, to display the html in angularjs

```
$scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
     '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
```

and needs to be injected ngsanitize to the module`angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])`,
and also needs to include dependency `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you use ng-bind-html, `$sanitize` needs to be injected at the module level as well.